# Android: Sharing Data between multiple applications

Tags: android, notifications, android-sharing

I have a requirement, wherein I have 4 android apps, which are sending notifications to a user, at a fixed time of the day. A user could have one, or more of these apps installed on his phone.

I want only one of the apps(any one) to show this notification to the user, because multiple apps popping up notifications is a bad user experience.

For this I need to share some data across the apps.
I was thinking of a mutex/lock based approach, the problem is, where do I store it?

Problems:

**Shared Prefs**: I don't know which app wrote the data first, and from which app's context should I read.

**SQLite**: Same Problem as above and app uninstalls need to be handled and SD card might be missing

**Server**: Mostly offline app, dont want to add internet permission just for this

I see files at a common location as the only way to store this information.
Is there any better way

Answer (score 1):

As you said that the easiest ways is with file,
I did this before and i too wasn't able to find more easy way.

when you show the notification first time then Just make a new file anywhere which can be common for any app and then check if file is exist.

if it exist then don't show the notification and if not then show and make file again, also remember to delete the file from any of your app when day changed, use AlarmManager for this.

hope it helps.